# Spring Boot, Jboss , Eclipse development environment

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to develop a spring boot application with REST API with JBOSS. As JBoss is not an embedded server, hence for very change in my source code during development needs to create a WAR and deploy it - which is really an additional step.

Is there any better way to automate it, so that my changes will immediately reflected to server?

Comment: You should be able to deploy to JBoss from within your IDE. You can use a tool such as HotSwapAgent (free) or JRebel (paid) to have java code changes reloaded on the fly.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Basically I am looking for to integrate/Intercept spring boot startup process to start the server. don't have any clue how to do it.

Comment: Nope. You simply build a war and deploy that to the server.